# JAX-RS + JPA, how to update/merge only a subset of an Entity's fields?

Tags: json, jpa, jax-rs

Suppose I have the following Entity:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType( XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class MyEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private long id;

    private boolean field1;

    private boolean field2;

    private boolean field3;
}
```

Suppose I have a REST Web Service that allows clients to POST partial or complete updates to a MyEntity resource. Perhaps the method signature looks something like this:

```
@POST
@Path("{id}")
public Response postMyEntity(@PathParam("id") long id, MyEntity myEntity)
```

Below is the JSON that a client might use to update only "field2" of MyEntity with id 101:

```
{
    "id": 101
    "field2": true
}
```

If JPA knew that only field2 was set during the de-serialization process then I'd love to persist this change with code as simple as:

```
entityManager.merge(myEntity);
```

However, this operation updates field1, field2, and field3.

How do people typically ensure that only the fields explicitly specified in the JSON/XML from the REST request are updated in the database? I've read about people using DTOs in their web service (as opposed to the Entities themselves) and manually figuring out what fields need to be set on the corresponding Entity...however, this use case seems so common that I'm surprised it would require a DIY approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps there is a better solution out there but I settled on forcing my REST service to produce and consume DTOs instead of Entities. My DTO classes never use primitives (Integer instead of int), which ensures that if a client omits a JSON/XML attribute then the corresponding DTO field will be null.

When I receive a POST to update a resource I:

1. Get the corresponding Entity from the database.
2. Copy all of the non-null fields from the DTO to the Entity.
3. Use JPA's merge functionality to update the database.

When I receive a GET for a resource I:

1. Get the Entity from the database.
2. Copy all of the fields from the Entity to a new DTO.
3. Return the DTO to the client.

Setting this up was tedious because it required me to:

1. Create a bunch of DTO classes that are nearly identical to the corresponding Entity classes.
2. Write logic to convert between DTOs and Entities.
3. Maintain this mess going forward.

Instead of using DTOs I suppose I could have eliminated primitives from my Entity classes and added not-null constraints to those fields. However, I read in several places that it is a "bad idea" to expose your Entity classes directly to REST clients. So I went ahead with the DTO solution even though I'm not the biggest fan of it.